# Initializing an array into a class definition

Tags: java, arrays, class

So, I'm doing a programming assignment and the assignment is to write a program that will print a calendar of a given month and year.  I'm writing the class to keep track of the name of the day of the week (Mon, Tues, Wed, Etc.), and I'm trying to give it 3 parameters:  The name of the day, a String, an int index, to refer to the third, an array of all the weekdays.  my opening code as is is thus:

```
public class Day
{

private String weekDay;
private String[] weekDays;
private int dayIndex;

weekDays = new String[7];

weekDays[1] = "Sunday";
weekDays[2] = "Monday";
weekDays[3] = "Tuesday";
weekDays[4] = "Wednesday";
weekDays[5] = "Thursday";
weekDays[6] = "Friday";
weekDays[7] = "Saturday";`
```

I'm getting errors when trying to do this, even though I have the syntax for the Array initialization correct.  I'm guessing this hassomething to do with the initializing of the array in the class definition on the first place?

The original design as suggested by my professor didn't have the index, just the `weekDay` and `weekDays[]` variables.  I wasn't sure what was intended for the array at all, so I figured I'd use an index and keep track of the day numerically that way.  Clearly it isn't working.  So one:  What is wrong with my solution above, and two:  Does anyone know what the original intention of the Day class would have been with just those 2 parameters?  The Idea of the Day class would have been to assist in figuring out what day of the week the particular month of the particular year started on, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks.  Sorry if I made any breaches of etiquette.

Comment: Dont't forget that arrays are indexed from 0 (not 1) in Java.

Comment: And that accessing weekDays by 7 will throw an IndexOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 1):

What errors are you getting? I'm not java but shouldn't your array be starting at 0?

```
weekDays[0] = "Sunday";
```

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't my problem, though.  I think I've got it.

Comment: cool, there's a couple of algorithms to determine that day of week using the date. see reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
private String[] weekDays =  new String[] {"Sunday", "Monday", 
                             "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero-based so starting from `1` rather than `0` will produce an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you attempt to assign the last `String`:

```
weekDays[7] = "Saturday";`
```

Also, non-declarative statements need to be in a method, constructor or static initializer rather than in the class block.

Instead of assigning the values individually, you could declare your `weekdays` to include the  values:

```
private String[] weekDays = { "Sunday", "Monday", ... };
```

This approach doesn't require you to specify array index values.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that last declaration solution, and see if that works.  That's sort of what I wanted to accomplish anyway.  Thanks.  Hopefully I don't still run into problems later.